# betterment of code in OO php

Tags: php, refactoring

I use php OO for my project. I have lots of families in my application around 7. So i have to use switch and do it in each file where i need to check the family. So i feel the performance is effected because of this. So is there any way so that i can eliminate these switch cases and use some design patters or something like that. The present idea is to have a separate code base for each family, which i am not satisfied with completely. So looking for various options to solve this issue.

Comment: Some code would help us help you.

Comment: @Mark Baker or Strategy - it depends..

Comment: @dantuch - possibly, without further information from the OP on exactly what he needs, it's hard to give accurate advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only quote Martin Fowler from his book Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code.

> Switch Statements
>
> One of the most obvious symptoms of
>   object-oriented code is its
>   comparative lack of switch (or case)
>   statements. The problem with switch
>   statements is essentially that of
>   duplication. Often you find the same
>   switch statement scattered about a
>   program in different places. If you
>   add a new clause to the switch, you
>   have to find all these switch,
>   statements and change them. The
>   object- oriented notion of
>   polymorphism gives you an elegant way
>   to deal with this problem.
>
> Most times you see a switch statement
>   you should consider polymorphism. The
>   issue is where the polymorphism should
>   occur. Often the switch statement
>   switches on a type code. You want the
>   method or class that hosts the type
>   code value. So use Extract Method to
>   extract the switch statement and then
>   Move Method to get it onto the class
>   where the polymorphism is needed. At
>   that point you have to decide whether
>   to Replace Type Code with Subclasses
>   or Replace Type Code with
>   State/Strategy. When you have set up
>   the inheritance structure, you can use
>   Replace Conditional with Polymorphism.

Consider buying and reading this book, it's one of the most precious works I have read.

Answer (score 1):

That pattern would be [Refactor Conditional With Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism).

The idea is to make those various family types into objects of their own. The linked article is taken from Martin Fowler's book [*Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#refactoring) that was already quoted in that other answer. In fact, the linked site has the entire contents of the book.

Additional information can be found at http://www.refactoring.com/